# prestashop admin site - display issue

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I have weird display issues while using prestashop admin.
see 2 screenshots.

[products delivery section (in french)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hcuB.png)
[drop down menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBbYm.png)

I am using MacOS Monterey (12.3.1) and I observe this issue on Google chrome, Mozilla Firefox and Safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. Thanks to this article https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/1011473-probl%C3%A8me-d-affichage-bo/

The issue is was the uncompatibility between PHP and Prestashop version.
When I set PHP to 7.2 per article, it works